# Integer64 class doesn't survive reshape2 melt function

Tags: r, class, dataframe, reshape2

I don't know whether this is an `integer64` (from `bit64`) problem, or a melt problem (from `reshape2`, but if I try to reshape a data.frame containing integer64 data then the class information is destroyed in the process and it reverts to the double representation:

```
library(bit64)
library(reshape2)

DF = data.frame(I =letters, Num1 = as.integer64(1:26), Num2 = as.integer64(1:26))
DFM = melt(DF, id.vars = "I")

sapply(DF, class)
sapply(DFM, class)
```

gives:

```
> sapply(DF, class)
          I        Num1        Num2 
   "factor" "integer64" "integer64" 
> sapply(DFM, class)
        I  variable     value 
 "factor"  "factor" "numeric"
```

And because integer64 is double underneath, the data is "corrupted"

```
> DF
   I Num1 Num2
1  a    1    1
2  b    2    2
3  c    3    3
4  d    4    4
5  e    5    5
...
> DFM
   I variable         value
1  a     Num1 4.940656e-324
2  b     Num1 9.881313e-324
3  c     Num1 1.482197e-323
4  d     Num1 1.976263e-323
5  e     Num1 2.470328e-323
6  f     Num1 2.964394e-323
```

What is causing this?  Is this a `integer64` problem or a `melt` problem?  When creating classes what can be done to avoid this sort of thing?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: sapply(DFM, class) gives "factor", "factor" and "integer64"

Comment: I am able to reproduce it.

Comment: Interesting, so what could be different between us?  Is there some version info or something else I could usefully give?

Comment: My fault, I accidentally loaded reshape and not reshape2. Interestingly, with reshape there is no problem.

Comment: @Corone, Look at [**page 9 here**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/bit64.pdf). The documentation states the limitations and they clearly state some issues with base R functions. For example, `is.vector(x=as.integer64(1:5))` would return `FALSE`!

Comment: @Arun, well spotted, it even talks about `unlist`.

Comment: @Arun - I'll accepted that as an answer if you repost.

Comment: @Arun `is.vector` is a red herring: it's false for any vector with attributes. `is.atomic` is the more important test.

Comment: @hadley, Thanks for correcting. You're right. What I wanted to say was from the documentation that `is.vector` doesn't automtically dispatch `is.vector.integer64` which would return `TRUE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems  to be a limitation of the package which is also mentioned in their documentation [**here on page 9**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/bit64.pdf). For example:

```
x <- data.frame(a=as.integer64(1:5), b=as.integer64(1:5))
> x
#   a b
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3
# 4 4 4
# 5 5 5

> unlist(x)

#            a1            a2            a3            a4            a5            b1 
# 4.940656e-324 9.881313e-324 1.482197e-323 1.976263e-323 2.470328e-323 4.940656e-324 
#            b2            b3            b4            b5 
# 9.881313e-324 1.482197e-323 1.976263e-323 2.470328e-323 

> as.matrix(x)
#                  a             b
# [1,] 4.940656e-324 4.940656e-324
# [2,] 9.881313e-324 9.881313e-324
# [3,] 1.482197e-323 1.482197e-323
# [4,] 1.976263e-323 1.976263e-323
# [5,] 2.470328e-323 2.470328e-323

x <- as.integer64(1:5)

> is.vector(x)
# [1] FALSE

> as.vector(x)
# [1] 4.940656e-324 9.881313e-324 1.482197e-323 1.976263e-323 2.470328e-323
```

Answer (score 5):

Resetting the class seems to 'correct' the results, see below. However, as was mentioned in the discussions this will most likely not work if the numeric values also contain other types than `integer64`.

```
> class(DFM$value) <- "integer64"
> DFM
   I variable value
1  a     Num1     1
2  b     Num1     2
3  c     Num1     3
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me in a similar case. Just a small caveat, the `NA`s turn into `9218868437227407266`...

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce it too.

Not a solution, but the problem seems to happen at the following line of `melt.data.frame` function :

```
value <- unlist(unname(data[var$measure]))
```

In your example, this leads to :

```
unlist(unname(DF[c("Num1","Num2")]))
```

And the `unlist` call changes the class of the data. As the help page says :

```
 The output type is determined from the highest type of the
 components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < real
 < complex < character < list < expression, after coercion of
 pairlists to lists.
```

Comment: So are we saying bit64 should have implemented unlist.integer64?

Comment: @Corone No, I don't think so. `unlist` converts its arguments because it has do deal with cases where they are not of the same class. For example `unlist(list(1,"a",TRUE))`. I don't know what the solution would be. Maybe, in melt, check if all the measure variables are of the same class, and in this case don't call `unlist`.

Comment: reshape uses rbind to put the measure variables underneath each other. rbind.integer64 is implemented in bit64. But even there you might run into the case where there are more variable types. Eventually everything needs to be converted to one type, which probably will always be numeric which is most general.

Comment: @juba one could just as easily request that unlist works on integer64 though - so "don't use unlist" isn't really a fix

Comment: @JanvanderLaan but in this case the ONLY type in the unlist is integer64, so when unlist casts to the "highest" it should still be integer64?

Comment: @Corone, yes of course it would be better if `unlist` worked on integer64. But as it is not a base R class, it's quite logical it doesn't, and as `unlist` doesn't seem to be implemented with S3 methods, I don't know how this could be done.

Comment: @juba and Corone, check the documentation I've cited as comment to the question.

Comment: In the short run, might be simpler to do `foo<-as.numeric(my_integer64_data)` and convert back when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

My integer64 problem arose because of getting data from postgres R library by using a query.

I solved this problem by writing a csv and then read it.

```
#integer64 issue!
write.csv(df, 'df.csv')
library(readr)
df <- read_csv("df.csv")
```

All numerical variables converted from integer64 to double or numericals.